# Using MSBuild to Copy a website into Production while REALLY skipping unchanged files

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I am using MSBuild to Publish a web site, then copy the published site to a web server on the same network. I set the copy command to "SkipUnchangedFiles."

It works swimmingly, but Skip Unchanged won't work because when I use AspNetCompiler to publish the website, each and every file is "new" -- its date is set to the moment of publishing, so even if the contents of a given file have not changed, the timestamp is different, so it's copied over anyway.

Is there a workaround that will prevent file whose contents have not changed from being copied?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're publishing the site, you may be able to do [Incremental Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx) instead of a full build.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing process for this as the deployment process isn't aware of the deployment target filesystem.

If you were aware you could do a diff using a tool like [beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) and then grab only the binary diff'ed items and copy those across.

Looking to automate this you are probably going to have to dig into writing msbuild targets or post build scripts.